# How to extract substrings from a string with whitespaces in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string that I got from webscraping using python. I wanna be able to get an output in a form like `{'XXXXXXXX':'AAAAAAAA','YYYYYYYY':'BBBBBBBB}` and hopefully put everything in a dataframe.

This is a sample of the very long string:

```
\\n    display:block\\u0022\\u003E\\n                                  div class= span_6\\u0022\\u003E\\n                                     li class=\\u0022borderbottom padleft pad20 nomargin\\u0022\\u003E\\n   span\\u003E1. XXXXXXXX\\/span\\u003E\\n                                strong class=\\u0022floatright\\u0022\\u003EAAAAAAAA\\/strong\\u003E\\n       \\/li\\u003E\\n                                                        li class=\\u0022borderbottom padleft pad20 nomargin\\u0022\\u003E\\n   span\\u003E2. YYYYYYYY\\/span\\u003E\\n                                strong class=\\u0022floatright\\u0022\\u003EBBBBBBBB\\/strong\\u003E\\n
```

#Blockquoting for clarity:

> \n    display:block\u0022\u003E\n
> div class= span_6\u0022\u003E\n
> li class=\u0022borderbottom padleft pad20 nomargin\u0022\u003E\n
> span\u003E1. **XXXXXXXX**\/span\u003E\n
> strong
> class=\u0022floatright\u0022\u003E**AAAAAAAA**\/strong\u003E\n
> \/li\u003E\n
> li class=\u0022borderbottom padleft pad20 nomargin\u0022\u003E\n
> span\u003E2. **YYYYYYYY**\/span\u003E\n
> strong
> class=\u0022floatright\u0022\u003E**BBBBBBBB**\/strong\u003E\n

I'm trying to do this:

```
#s = the string 
pattern = "u003E\|(.*?)\|\\/strong"
substring = re.search(pattern, s).group(1) 
print(substring)
```

but its failing. What's the best way to do this?

Edit:
Expected output is two lists:

```
list1 = ['XXXXXXXX','YYYYYYYY']
list2 = ['AAAAAAAA','BBBBBBBB']
```

Comment: First use strip() function

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Hope to be able to put it in a dictionary like d ={'XXXXXXXX':'AAAAAAAA','YYYYYYYY':'BBBBBBBB}, by doing loops. But I cant even extract the 'XXXXXXXX', let alone put it in a dictionary. sorry for being a newbie

Comment: @nununu the expected output is unclear. Based on your given example `\\n    display:block\\u0022...`, you have to update the question with an example result you want with that long string. Should it be `{"display": "block"}`? Or something else? Only you would know this.

Comment: What you posted there looks like messed up html `\\u0022\\u003E` = `">`. This probably means that you have valid html somewhere that you could parse with beautiful soup.

Comment: Butchering your HTML so it no longer makes sense is probably the root problem here.

Comment: Did my answer help? I can adjust it if you provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a solution like

```py
import re
s = '\\n    display:block\\u0022\\u003E\\n                                  div class= span_6\\u0022\\u003E\\n                                     li class=\\u0022borderbottom padleft pad20 nomargin\\u0022\\u003E\\n   span\\u003E1. XXXXXXXX\\/span\\u003E\\n                                strong class=\\u0022floatright\\u0022\\u003EAAAAAAAA\\/strong\\u003E\\n       \\/li\\u003E\\n                                                        li class=\\u0022borderbottom padleft pad20 nomargin\\u0022\\u003E\\n   span\\u003E2. YYYYYYYY\\/span\\u003E\\n                                strong class=\\u0022floatright\\u0022\\u003EBBBBBBBB\\/strong\\u003E\\n'
unescaped_s = s.encode('latin-1', 'backslashreplace').decode('unicode-escape')
pattern = r">\d+\.\s*([^<>]*)\\/span>\s*[^>]*>([^<>]*)\\/strong"
substrings = re.findall(pattern, unescaped_s)
print(dict(substrings))
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/Io7DoQ). First, the string is unescaped, and the regex is applied to the unescaped input string version.

The [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jHuegv/2/) is

```py
>\d+\.\s*([^<>]*)\\/span>\s*[^>]*>([^<>]*)\\/strong
```

*Details*:

- `>` - a `>` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^<>]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `\\/span>` - `\/span>` text
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[^>]*>` - any zero or more chars other than `>` and then a `>` char
- `([^<>]*)` - Group 2: zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `\\/strong` - a `\/strong>` text.